# iPhone storage is full while iCloud is empty

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, storage

What can I send to iCloud and how do I do that? My iPhone is full and my iCloud has barely been used. Can you help me please?

Comment: What I found out is that even though I have 2TB iCloud storage, Apple will download files to fill up my 64GB iPhone claiming that they are recent files!

Answer (score 2):

The biggest thing that takes up storage is photos. If you're running iOS 9 or later, then go to Settings -> iCloud -> Photos and enable iCloud Photo Library. Then, make sure optimize iPhone storage is checked. Also, delete any apps that you may not use. Pay close attention to games. They eat up the most space. Switching to a streaming music service like Music or Spotify will also let you free up space by deleting music on your device.

Comment: Optimize photos didn't work for me. I bought 200gb but having extensive photos means the thumbnail cache takes up space. So you end up paying for cloud storage but don't have more storage available on your phone. In thought, a good idea but execution terrible. Dropbox with project infinite or Google photos is better execution.

Answer (score 0):

You mean your iPhone storage is full and you you want to back up some data on iCloud so that you can have more storage on your iPhone, am I correct?

Now, I'd like to share with you how to turn on and use iCloud.

Go to Settings → iCloud to see all the settings and options on your iPhone or iPad. If you have not turned iCloud on already this is where you can log in to iCloud with your Apple ID and password. After you log in you will see options to turn on iCloud options which control what iCloud can do. Most users will want to leave these iCloud options turned on. When turned on, the options sync to iCloud so that they are accessible on iCloud.com and on your other Apple devices.

You can toggle any options you don’t want to the off position to stop syncing that data with your devices and iCloud. Any of the settings with an On > option offers more information and settings that you can control. These include iCloud Drive, Photos, Backup, Keychain and Find My iPhone.

If you want to know how to make more space, you can try other ways, such as clean up caches and temporary files, maybe iMyfone Umate is a good choice for you.

Have you installed the app "WhatsApp"? Seems it was the app "WhatsApp", creating lots of cache files and stealing storage from the phone. You should try to install the update and see whether the storage came back to normal.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can go to Setting>General>Usage to check what us takes up your iPhone storage.
Mostly, there are photos, videos, songs etc. So you can thansfer these data to iCloud.

You can also backup all your data to iCloud and then delete backup, and photos, videos, songs from your iPhone. So as to get storage on iPhone.

To get more storage back, you can also try to delete the junk files, such as Safari cookies, caches, history etc. And the fast way to do this is uninstall and reinstall the app who eat up you so much storage.